# Connect and perform READ/WRITE operation on OTG Device (Pendrive) in IONIC App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

We want to get data from an OTG Device (Pendrive) in our IONIC App and send that data to server or to in email the data. Now we are just able connect the device to an android mobile, but it is not showing in app. Where as External SDcard is working fine, we can see SDCard data in ionic app and also use that data for further activities.

Please guide us how to connect OTG Pendrive to IONIC app and use data in it for app.

Comment: You can try the [getExternalSdCardDetails()](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#getexternalsdcarddetails) in [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) which should return its location on the filesystem.

Comment: @DaveAlden Thanks for your support. But by using your given link data, we are just able to access SDCard data but not OTG device data in IONIC app.

Comment: Don't be confused: the purpose of this plugin method is to access *external removable storage* (physical SD cards, etc.). The "SD Card" as defined by Cordova is actually physically on internal storage.

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/140282